# Are these 3 terms referring to the same concept: O365 distribution group, O365 group and O365 distribution list?

Tags: azure, office365

I am hoping to get some help about O365 terms. These 3 terms to me seem to be the same thing but I am looking for confirmation. Are these 3 terms referring to the same concept: O365 distribution group, O365 group and O365 distribution list?

If I should be asking this in any other stackexchange forum then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O365 distribution group and O365 distribution list are the same concept, distribution groups are sometimes called distribution lists.

But there are some differences between **O365 distribution group (list)** and **O365 group**. According to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/create-groups/compare-groups?view=o365-worldwide):

> **Microsoft 365 groups** (formerly Office 365 groups) are used for collaboration between users, both inside and outside your company.
>
> **Distribution groups** are used for sending email notifications to a group of people.

It can be seen from this that: A **distribution groups** is a list of email addresses that can be used to send emails to multiple recipients without entering each destination email address manually. **Office 365 Groups** is a special cross-application service used to communicate with teams Of other users collaborate and edit documents according to a strategy defined at the team level or project level.    The Office 365 group is a feature, but not a separate product.

Although Microsoft 365 groups and distribution groups have similarities, they also have many [differences](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/office-365-groups-vs-distribution-lists/). You can understand that Microsoft 365 groups are an enhanced version of distribution groups. However, as the official doc says, distribution groups can also be [upgraded to Microsoft 365 groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/upgrade-distribution-lists?view=o365-worldwide).